# Symfony return only one choice

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a very simple problem with symfony 2.7 and form : with Formbuilder, I have "choice" type and two similar label (but different key). Symfony print only one label. Can you help me ?

```
        $builder->add('droit', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Droits',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices' => array("a" => "test", "b" => "test"),
        'mapped' => false
    ));
```

I have just one "test" on twig form ... but I have two key.

Answer (score 2):

You should only pass model values to your choices and use the option `choice_label`:

```
$builder->add('droit', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'Droits', // Global label of the choice field
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices' => array("a", "b"), // Your choice model values
    'choices_as_values' => true, // forward compatibility with symfony3
    'choice_label' => function () {
        return 'Droit'; // Each choice label
    },
    'mapped' => false,
));
```

See the [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label).

Answer (score -1):

use 'choices_as_values' => false or change the format of the choices array to: array("test" => "a", "test" => "b")

Comment: In your example the first value is overridden.

Comment: This is the same as `array("test" => "b")`.

Comment: you are right. did you try 'choices_as_values' => false  or 'choices_as_values' => true ?

Comment: I'm not the one asking :p